# Terraform stop command

Tags: oracle, terraform, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

I'm new to terraform. I wrote a terraform code to provision an instance to oracle cloud infrastructure and it works fine. Somehow the problem is there is no "stop" command in terraform cmd, they only have "destroy" command.
Is there any way to stop resources instead of destroying it?

Comment: Not really. You could stop the instance manually and it won't affect the state file.

Comment: If you are using `opc_compute_instance` from the Oracle Cloud Infrastructure Classic provider with `desired_state` you can achieve this https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/opc/r/opc_compute_instance.html#desired_state

Comment: You could implement it by passing an input variable to the terraform like "stop" or empty otherwise. Then add a conditional null_resource and add a 'provisioner "local-exec"' where you can run a cli command to stop the instance. https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/null/latest/docs/resources/resource

Answer (score 2):

if you are looking for a solution, there is no such option currently. You can request for a feature [here](https://github.com/terraform-providers/terraform-provider-oci)

As a temporary workaround, you could toy with **user_data** and update and send a shutdown request using it. i.e. `terraform apply`

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using Terraform for Provisioning (Apply) and Termination (Destroy). Stopping/Starting the instance through OCI CLI is simple and can be done easily through a simple shell script such as this.

This is less complex and easily maintainable for simpler requirements.

### Instance.sh File

oci compute instance action --action $1  --instance-id ocid1.instance.oc1.iad.an.....7d3xamffeq

Start Command:
$ source Instance.sh start

Stop Command:
$ source Instance.sh stop

Answer (score 0):

You also have an option of setting up Functions that can manage the lifecycle actions. There is already a public solution such as the one below in case you would like to pursue further.

https://github.com/AnykeyNL/OCI-AutoScale/blob/master/AutoScaleALL.py